# How to make nested divs sortable after drag and drop in jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

Hi all i have scenario where user can drag and drop layouts in a container and then content also can dropped in the layouts

sample structure of html will be like this

```
   <div class="box-container">

   <div style="display: block;" class="box">
       <div class="div-header">Content</div>
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span12">
                <div class="panel ui-droppable ui-draggable">
                    <div style="display: block;" class="box">
<div class="div-header">Content</div>
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span12">
                <div class="panel ui-droppable ui-draggable">
                    <a href="/index" >
                    <img src="http://myntra.myntassets.com/assets/banners/2014/4/10/1397140384493-fashion-fing_HPB_612_459_mini.jpg"  /></a>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
                    <div style="display: block;" class="box">
        <div class="div-header">Content</div>
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span12">
                <div class="panel ui-droppable ui-draggable">
                    <a href="/index" >
                    <img src="http://myntra.myntassets.com/assets/banners/2014/4/10/1397140384493-fashion-fing_HPB_612_459_mini.jpg"  /></a>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
                    <a href="/index" >
                    <img src="http://myntra.myntassets.com/assets/banners/2014/4/10/1397140384493-fashion-fing_HPB_612_459_mini.jpg"  /></a>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


   <div style="display: block;" class="box">
      <div class="div-header">Content</div>
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span12">
                <div class="panel ui-droppable ui-draggable">
                    <div style="display: block;" class="box">
<div class="div-header">Content</div>
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span12">
                <div class="panel ui-droppable ui-draggable">
                    <a href="/index" >
                    <img src="http://myntra.myntassets.com/assets/banners/2014/4/10/1397140384493-fashion-fing_HPB_612_459_mini.jpg"  /></a>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" >
                    <img src="http://myntra.myntassets.com/assets/banners/2014/4/9/1397022695018-ed-hardy_HPB_612_459_mini.jpg"  />

                    </a>
                     <div style="display: block;" class="box">
<div class="div-header">Content</div>
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span12">
                <div class="panel ui-droppable ui-draggable">
                    <a href="/index" >
                    <img src="http://myntra.myntassets.com/assets/banners/2014/4/10/1397140384493-fashion-fing_HPB_612_459_mini.jpg"  /></a>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

box-container holds the all the boxes now what i want to do is make all the boxes sortable in the box-container and any boxes in the box to these boxes can be nested how to apply sortable here can any one help me out here

here is the fiddle with the html how it looks

```
 http://jsfiddle.net/CyJ8h/
```

Comment: can you post a fiddle please

Comment: @Bryan added fiddle can you check that